# How to Detect if sms code is sent to another device with PhoneAuthProvider in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using PhoneAuthProvider in firebase, my users experience a problem when they they accidentally key in another phone number that is not in their devices. What happens is that the sms code is sent to that phone number but I have no way of detecting that to trigger the necessary actions.

```
@Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {


            try {

                Toast.makeText( RegistrationStepOne.this, "Phone number verified successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

                Intent step1=new Intent(RegistrationStepOne.this,RegistrationStepTwo.class);
                Bundle extraMain = new Bundle();
                extraMain.putString( "phoneNumber", getPhoneNo.getText().toString());
                step1.putExtras( extraMain );
                startActivity(step1);
                RegistrationStepOne.this.finish();


            } catch (NullPointerException b) {
                b.printStackTrace();
                passDialog.dismiss();
            }


        }
```

The method above can't detect that and neither are the ones below

```
@Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Log.d( "FEL", e.getLocalizedMessage() );

            verifyCode.setText( "Resend Request" );

            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {

            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                Toast.makeText( RegistrationStepOne.this, "Too Many Requests Sent...Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {

            Log.d( TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId );
            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            mResendToken = token;

        }
```

Where and how I am I supposed to detect that verification was not successful if code is received by another device

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You could set a toast or something saying that the sms was sent to *phone number*. If that is not the number please try again. Other than that i don't think you can do much

Comment: Where exactly do I set that toast when non of the methods can detect such situation?

Comment: The way i would do it would be, user enters the phone number and i guess he presses a button to send the sms. When the button is pressed other than calling the firebase method make that toast so the user can read again the phonenumber. If the phone number was ok the user will get the message, if not the user will see the wrong phone number and should have the option to send the sms again to a different number.

Comment: That can do the work around but it's not stable enough, still prone to human errors. Anyways I will use  that at the moment until firebase resolves the situation.

Comment: 99% of the apps are prone to human errors, there is no way to make it monkey proof... Even facebook has this kind of error when yo first enter your phone number

Comment: Ok thanks though my boss doesn't understand that